# Different template on angular

Tags: angularjs

On my HTML code I want to display either a gallery of images or just one image ... The templates are different:

```
if (mode = 0) {

  <div data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">

    <div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images'>
      <img data-ng-src="image.Url"/>
      // Some more code
    </div>

  </div>

} else {

  <div data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="image">
    <img src="data-ng-src="{image.Url}" />
    // Other code
  </div>

}
```

On angular controller I have the following:

```
application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService) {

  $scope.model = {
    images: []
  }

  var init = function () {
     ImageService.GetList($scope.model.pages.instagram)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.model.images = $scope.model.images.concat(data.Images);
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
```

}

How to modify the controller to display either a list of images or one single image?

Comment: which language is that : if (mode = 0) {

  <div data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">

Comment: That is pseudo code but it is coming from the server ... It is ASP.NET MVC Razor. So in fact I have: @if (Model.Mode == ModeType.Gallery) { ...

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.isMultiple = '@RazorIsMultiple';
  </script>


<div data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">
  <!--<input type="hidden" data-ng-model="mode.isMultiple" value="@RazorIsMultiple"/>-->
  <div data-ng-if="mode.isMultiple" data-ng-repeat='image in model.images'>
    <img data-ng-src="image.Url"/>
    // Some more code
  </div>

  <img data-ng-if="!mode.isMultiple" src="data-ng-src="{image.Url}" />
    // Other code
</div>
```

and in your controller, add something like that :

during init of the controller

```
$scope.mode = {};
//$scope.$watch('mode.isMultiple', function(newVal, oldVal){
//     //insert your logic here
//});
$scope.mode.isMultiple = window.isMultiple;
```

Comment: The problem here is that the call to the API is different. So when I am display a gallery I am calling an API method ... When I am displaying one image only I am calling another method ... So this is like having two different controller inits ...

Comment: I've edited my answer with something I think is feasible, but that I never tried so far

Comment: That does not work ... I logged the newVal and oldVal and they are both undefined ... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: $watch was only triggered once?, if you change the type hidden to text, do you see it properly displayed?

Comment: Yes, only triggered once. I changed it to text and it shows false even if I have: <input type="text" data-ng-model="mode.isMultiple" data-ng-value="true" />  ... Which means is reading the value from the model, right. But not doing the other way around ...